# How to upload files which are other than English names?

Tags: commerce, files

In Drupal, how to upload files which are other than English names?

The problem I am facing is that when I upload files for which their name is other than English their name changes to an unknown format in the file directory, like:

```
áˆ¾áŒáˆ®á‰½áŠ“ áˆ¨á‹³á‰µ á‹¨á‰µáˆ­á áŠ á‰ áˆ  áŠ¨áŒá‰¥áˆ­ áŠáƒ_2
```

Any help?

Comment: I tested using your name and got the áŠ¨áˆ˜á‰€áŒ áˆ­ á‹¨á‰°áŒˆáŠ˜ áŒˆá‰¢ áˆ‹á‹­ á‹¨á‰°áŠ¨áˆáˆˆ áŒá‰¥áˆ­_0 name on the server.. But when the file is downloaded again through Drupal, the file name is correct.

Comment: so nial whats the solution?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> Provides one-way string transliteration (romanization) and cleans file names during upload by replacing unwanted characters.
>
> Generally spoken, it takes Unicode text and tries to represent it in US-ASCII characters (universally displayable, unaccented characters) by attempting to transliterate the pronunciation expressed by the text in some other writing system to Roman letters.

Here is a sample of what this module does for "**file names**":

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Pierre.Vriens, but i tried it and its cool module but what i want is to display the actual name of the upload file not the translated english name.

Comment: the name of the file is " ከመቀጠር የተገኘ ገቢ ላይ የተከፈለ ግብር.pdf " but when i upload it ,it is stored as " áŠ¨áˆ˜á‰€áŒ áˆ­ á‹¨á‰°áŒˆáŠ˜ áŒˆá‰¢ áˆ‹á‹­ á‹¨á‰°áŠ¨áˆáˆˆ áŒá‰¥áˆ­_0.pdf " ,,the translerate module changes the name to english i dont need that i just want it to be sored as " ከመቀጠር የተገኘ ገቢ ላይ የተከፈለ ግብር.pdf  ",,thanks!